# multiple Density plot using R

Tags: r

I am thinking about plotting multiple density plots on a single graph.My situation is this: I have a query result that has three different columns

```
CustomerID  Group  AvgVisitsperday
1             grp1        10
2             grp1        20
3             grp2        30
4             grp3        40
5             grp2        15
6             grp2         5
```

I have around 50,000 rows of data. I want to plot 3 density plots with three different colors that would represent the 3 distint groups and their average visits on a single graph..I feel that the density plot would be ideal to represent the distribution..Any ideas or thoughts on this, please feel free to comment. I have been able to do one density plot using R but not able to do group wise.. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the `ggplot2` package:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=AvgVisitsperday, color=Group)) + stat_density(fill=NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's reasonably easy to use the output of `density` with base graphics. The estimate comes out with $x and $y components, so plotting one, then adding the others with `lines` works quite well.

```
plot(density( subset(dfrm, Group=='GrpA', AvgVisitsperday), na,rm=TRUE) )  
with( density( subset(dfrm, Group=='GrpB', AvgVisitsperday), na,rm=TRUE) ,
      lines(x,y)
with( density( subset(dfrm, Group=='GrpC', AvgVisitsperday), na,rm=TRUE) ,
      lines(x,y)
```

With lattice:

```
require(lattice)
densityplot( ~ AvgVisitsperday, groups=Group, data=dfrm)
```